# How to approve a new phone model in Ecuador?

Tags: cellphones, ecuador, gsm-mobile

A few weeks ago, I bought a SIM from Claro Ecuador to use in a fairly recent cellphone. I had several Claro SIMs over the years when traveling around Ecuador in different phones and they never triggered a countdown to being blocked. The new cellphone though receives this message every few days:

> Hola. Tu equipo sera bloqueado en 25 dias, debido a que no cumple con
> la normative vigente para functional en el pais. Informate en **BROKEN
> LINK**

This roughly translates to: *Your phone will be blocked in 25 days since it does not comply with the norms to function in the country*. The link provided for more imported is always broken, returning a 404 page on the Claro website.

Speaking to Claro support they says that this was not their issue but that I had to file a homologation process with Arcotel, which is a [free online service](https://www.arcotel.gob.ec/tramite-gratuito-de-homologacion-en-linea/).

After registration, the form provides requires an IMEI, a brand and model. Upon submission it does some checks and verifies the consistency of the information. Unfortunately, the model of my new phone is not on the list and so it fails validation. I have tried dozens of other models from the same brand and other brands of the same company but it always fails.

It seems wrong that they force a model selection when the assumption is that the form is being filled because this is a phone not known to Arcotel!

Is there any way to pass homologation with a new phone model or change some settings on the phone so that it complies with the norms to operate in Ecuador?

Comment: Sorry but I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel.

Comment: Is it possible that once the check is passed that the question won't be asked again?  IE if you stick your SIM into a known good phone, Arcotel will mark your SIM as being inserted into a compliant phone, and won't care if you swap back.

Comment: @chx It is about travel because the form is about adding a phone purchased outside the country. People in Ecuador will not get the message if they bought a phone in the country. This is about someone trying to get cell service in Ecuador when they have travelling because their phone is not one sold in Ecuador. The Arcotel page mentions the foreign phone as the purpose of the form.

Comment: @PeterM Well, I do not know. I don't know when they check. If the IMEI is sent every time the phone connects to the local network, then this may very well happen again after swapping it back. Of course, the new phone is because my old one died but I could try on my wife's phone which is older and did not get that message.

Comment: One alternative is to use something like Google Fi with free international roaming, entirely sidestepping the unreasonable local requirements. I had the same problem in Uzbekistan.

Comment: Where did you buy your cellphone and what model is it?

Comment: It was bought in Canada and it is a OnePlus Nord CE 2 5G. The Arcotel website unfortunately has only a dozen OnePlus models and many newer ones are missing, presumably because they are not sold in Ecuador.